# Running SQL scripts with Powershell Special character not executed properly

Tags: powershell, special-characters, sqlcmd

I am running sql scripts through PowerShell It works fine but when there is this particular character "**ô**" it is converted to this character < ? > . 
How can I solve this issue ? I am attaching the powershell code below .

P.S  I can only make changes in the powershell script I cannot change the SQL scripts

**PowerShell Script**

```
 Invoke-sqlcmd -inputfile "C:\DailyPatch\extracted\CureMD.sql"-database $text[$i]-OutputSqlErrors $true|Out-File -filePath "C:\DailyPatch\dbname.txt"
```

Comment: Check that your CureMD.sql file is saved in UTF-8.

Comment: Is that `ô` (Latin Small Letter O With Circumflex) displayed correctly running your script in `powershell_ise`?

Comment: @DavidBrabant no its not

Comment: Try [customizing your command prompt window](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/stupid-geek-tricks-enable-more-fonts-for-the-windows-command-prompt/): force `Lucida Console` or `Courier New` or (downloadable) `DejaVu Sans Mono` font. The same procedure is appliable to `Powershell` window if it does not inherit from `cmd`. Apply to Windows XP and above.